# TSQL ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE Function In Sql Server 2019

Tags: t-sql, sql-function, sql-server-2019

So I have simple string encryption wrapper function like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.FncStringEncrypt(
    @Cipher NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Text NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Salt NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN

    IF @Cipher IS NULL OR @Cipher = ''
    BEGIN
        RETURN NULL
    END

    IF @Text IS NULL OR @Text = ''
    BEGIN
        RETURN NULL
    END


    DECLARE @_encryptionBinary varbinary(max)

    IF @Salt IS NOT NULL AND 
        @Salt <> ''
    BEGIN
        set @_encryptionBinary = ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE(@Cipher, @Text, 1, @Salt)
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        set @_encryptionBinary = ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE(@Cipher, @Text)
    END


    RETURN cast('' as xml).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:variable("@_encryptionBinary"))', 'varchar(max)')

END
```

Tried in various Version 14 and lower versioned machines , it works fine.
When I use it in Sql Server 2019 (Version: 15.0.2070.41) I get the error message:

*Msg 596, Level 21, State 1, Line 0
Cannot continue the execution because the session is in the kill state.
Msg 0, Level 20, State 0, Line 0
A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.
Completion time: 2020-06-13T20:32:25.6110034+03:00*

But weirdly if I use **ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE** on its own then it works on every versions:

```
SELECT ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('aglmule','ilemak',1,'ilemak')
```

Comment: I suspect this is an inlining issue. If you disable inlining (using `WITH INLINE = OFF` in the function's definition) do you get the same behaviour? [Disabling Scalar UDF Inlining without changing the compatibility level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/scalar-udf-inlining?view=sql-server-ver15#disabling-scalar-udf-inlining-without-changing-the-compatibility-level)

Comment: @Larnu's suspicion is correct. I see an access violation in the error log when using the function unless I specify the hint or turn off the `TSQL_SCALAR_UDF_INLINING` database scoped configuration.

Comment: appreciate the answers. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You should upgrade to [SQL Server 2019 CU4](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4548597/cumulative-update-4-for-sql-server-2019) or later, where [several inlining issues](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4538581/fix-scalar-udf-inlining-issues-in-sql-server-2019) were fixed (besides [those that were fixed in CU2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4538581/fix-scalar-udf-inlining-issues-in-sql-server-2019)).